# how to filter number of posts per page in Django python

Tags: django, pagination

**This is views.py file**

```
    paginator = Paginator(
        product_list,
        5
    )
    show_on_page = request.GET.get('show_on_page', 5)
    product_item_list = paginator.get_page(show_on_page)
```

and this is my templates file

```
<div class="show-on-page">
    <label class="product-sort-label" for="show-on-page">Tonen op pagina:</label>
    <select name="show-on-page" id="show-on-page">
        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
```

I want to add random navigation like when you select 5 from dropdown 5 posts should be displayed per page if 10 it selects 10 posts. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

i can imagine, you are mean:

```
...
show_on_page = request.GET.get('show_on_page', 5)
paginator = Paginator(product_list, show_on_page)
product_item_list = paginator.get_page(page_number_getfrom_request)
...
```

but why you are not use ListView from Django GCBV:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    model = Products

    def get_paginate_by(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.GET.get('show_on_page') or super().get_paginate_by(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what does page_number_get_from_request means?

Comment: it means: if you want to see some objects from product list, which are not on the first page, you can say, which page paginator should show right now.